# What is "Request Signing Certificate" used for?

Tags: single-sign-on, okta

Does anyone know what this certificate is used for? We use Okta as IDP and the SSO work well even though I didn't upload this certificate into Okta.

[image]

Comment: Does the answer posted below resolve your question?

Comment: We just stopped using this certificate. The SSO providers cert is not self-sign and has a long duration, which works well for us.

Comment: @Thomas Welcome to the site! Your answers was flagged as "not an answer" by the community, and it didn't really answer the question posted so I converted it to comment (you won't be able to comment yet until you earn a little more rep). Hope you stick around!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_saml_idp_values.htm):

> **Request Signing Certificate**: The certificate used to generate the signature on a SAML request to the identity provider. This signing certificate is used when Salesforce is the service provider for a service provider-initiated SAML login. You save the signing certificate from the Certificate and Key Management Set up page.

Service Provider(SP) initiated login means when users access Salesforce login page first, and then sends an authorization request to the Identity Provider (IDP). Once the IdP authenticates the user's identity, the user is logged into Salesforce. The request signing certificate is used in this SP-initiated SAML login flow.

If your SP-initiated login is working fine, then most probably this certificate is not used by the IDP (which is Okta in your case)

You might want to contact Okta help center again to confirm but there is an [old Okta post](https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D50Z00008C3jZL/does-okta-validate-signature-on-saml-authentication-requests) which mentions the following:

> Okta currently doesn't validate AuthnRequest signatures....

Comment: Okta still doesn't validate signatures on the request.

Comment: For others like myself wondering, Azure AD does not validate this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#signature